# How to return different types in v8

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion, v8

I have not been able to find a general list for returning different types in [v8](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Data.html). For instance to return an Number in v8 you would do

```
Handle<Value> some_function(const v8::Arguments& args)
{   
    HandleScope scope;

    int x;
    return scope.Close(Number::New(x)); 
}
```

How would I do this for `v8::Number`, `v8::Boolean`, `v8::String` and `v8::Object`?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 kinds of primitive type in v8. Boolean, Number(Integer) and String. However, v8 also support object type for value such as array, date, function, and so on. v8 API references will be helpful for you. http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Data.html

Comment: and...

`return scope.Close( Null() );`

if you have the urge to return a JavaScript `null`.

Depending on API version you may have to pass Isolate to `Null(isolate)`.